# I want to know how to set path for environment variable in slitaz

Tags: linux

I am using linux slitaz. and i ve installed the java 1.6.17. and now i ve to set path for environment variable.
  how to do this , can anyone give solution???

Answer (score 0):

Just set it:

```
$ export MY_ENV_VAR=foo
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using bash, then in your `~/.bash_profile`, add the following line:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/java/latest/bin
```

Or wherever you installed Java.

Answer (score 0):

```
bash: export PATH=$PATH:/the/path/you/want

csh or tcsh: setenv PATH $PATH:/the/path/you/want
```

If you don't know what path you're using, try: `echo $SHELL` and this will tell you.

NOTE:  The `$PATH` allows you to just append your new path to the current one.  That way you don't lose your current path.